# PHP Sql Adding New Articles

Tags: php, sql

Need help with some PHP and MySQL I cant find were I went wrong..

Trying to add new blog article using a function call. I know all other code is correct because if I manually add entry into database sql it shows on blog. When adding a new entry to database sql it never adds into the database.. Any one notice anything wrong?

I have functions for time and date of post and they all work. If I can figure out this part I can fix the tags too. If any one would like to see in a txt file just let me know its hard to post straight code to here...

```
function eb_admin_newarticle()
{
    global $lang;
    $output="\t\t".ucwords($lang['new_article'])."\r\n";;
    //To add new article post
    if(!empty($_POST['text']))
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
            $_POST[$key]=str_replace("Acirc;","",$value);
        $sql="INSERT INTO eb_articles SET article_flag=".$_POST['sticky'].",article_date=\"".time()."\",author_id=\"".$_SESSION['user_id-'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]."\", article_title=\"".str_replace("\"","&quot;",$_POST['title'])."\",article_body=\"".$_POST['text']."\",article_comments=".$_POST['comments'];
        mysql_query($sql);

        $article_id=mysql_insert_id();
        //input tags on article
        if(strlen($_POST['tags'])>1) {
            $tags=explode(",",$_POST['tags']);
            foreach($tags as $tag) {
                $sql="INSERT INTO eb_tags SET tag_name=\"".$tag."\"";
                mysql_query($sql);
                if(mysql_affected_rows()==1)
                    $tag_ids[]=mysql_insert_id();
                else
                    $tag_ids[]=mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT tag_id FROM eb_tags WHERE tag_name=\"".$tag."\""),0);
            }
            foreach($tag_ids as $tag_id)
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO eb_tags_links SET tag_id=".$tag_id.",article_id=".$article_id);
        }

        header('Location: news.php?id='.$article_id);
    }
    else {
        $output.="\t\t<form action=\"admin.php?id=newarticle\" method=\"post\">\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t\t<p><b>".ucwords($lang['title'])."</b><br /><input class=\"inputtext\" type=\"text\" name=\"title\" /></p>\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t\t<textarea id=\"text\" name=\"text\"></textarea>\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t\t<p><b>".ucwords($lang['tags'])."</b><br />".$lang['tag_seperate']."<br /><input type=\"text\" class=\"inputtext\" name=\"tags\" /></p>\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t\t<p><b>".ucwords($lang['sticky'])."</b><br /><input type=\"radio\" name=\"sticky\" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\" /> ".ucwords($lang['no'])."<br /><input type=\"radio\" name=\"sticky\" value=\"2\" /> ".ucwords($lang['yes'])."</p>\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t\t<p><b>".ucwords($lang['comments'])."</b><br /><input type=\"radio\" name=\"comments\" value=\"0\" /> ".ucwords($lang['no'])."<br /><input type=\"radio\" name=\"comments\" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\" /> ".ucwords($lang['yes'])."</p>\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t\t<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"".ucwords($lang['save'])."\" /></p>\r\n";
        $output.="\t\t</form>\r\n";
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for code formatting!

Answer (score 2):

First things first

- **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.**
  A malicious user could easily wipe out your entire table.
- **You should also always use `exit;` after a header redirect.**
  When you send a `header`, the page will still keep executing. Besides, it's only a suggestion to the browser. A malicious user could make his browser ignore the header and load the page anyway.
- **You're making a ton of unnecessary queries.**
  After having added a tag to the database, you're getting the tag ID with another query. The tag ID is already in `mysql_insert_id()`. No need to query the database.
  If you want to add 10 articles to the database, you're making 10 queries. This is completely unnecessary. See the MySQL manuals on how to do this using one query.
- **You shouldn't even be using `mysql_*`!**
  It's deprecated and bad style! Go find a tutorial for `mysqli` or PDO, don't relay on articles from 2008!

**Regarding the actual question**, try some debugging yourself. You're not checking if any of your queries succeed. When you perform a query, `mysql_query()` returns either a resource or `FALSE` on failure. Check if this is happening, so you can find out where exactly the error is happening.

One thing that might be causing this, is your lack of encapsulation. E.g., you need to replace

```
$sql="INSERT INTO eb_articles SET article_flag=".$_POST['sticky'].", ...
```

with

```
$sql="INSERT INTO eb_articles SET article_flag='".$_POST['sticky']."', ...
```

This goes for everywhere, always encapsulate content with `'`. That should solve the problem at hand, but you application is still very vulnerable.

Comment: i do apologize for the lack of taging on this site.. And Yes lots of parts are dangerous and this is why i have not went public.. Ty and i see i forgot to add in syntax. I will write an error page my eyes hurt.. But i do know if i add the database entry in with like "phpmyadmin" or something like that it works.

Comment: You misunderstand. Instead of doing just `mysql_query(...)`,  you need to do `if (mysql_query(...)) { ... } else { // log error, etc. }`.

Comment: srry i am new to sql scripting

Comment: **It Be HelpFull if i did**
    `$sql="INSERT INTO eb_articles SET article_title='\"".str_replace("\"","&quot;",$_POST['title'])."\"',article_body='\"".$_POST['text']."\"',article_comments='".$_POST['comments'];`
**or**

    `$sql="INSERT INTO eb_articles (article_title, article_body, article_comments) VALUES
    ('$_POST['title']','$_POST['text']',$_POST['comments'])"`

**and to check for error prolly something like this?**

    `if (!mysql_query($sql)){ die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";`

Comment: I should just quit and look at it tomorrow with fresh eyes thx for help

Comment: No Worries I fixed It Problem was a Database input error one of the databases were named wrong ty